# unpack requires a string argument of length 24

Tags: python

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here but I am trying to open a file, trace1.flow, read the header information then throw the source IP and destination IP into dictionaries.  This is done in Python running on a Fedora VM.  I am getting the following error:

```
(secs, nsecs, booted, exporter, mySourceIP, myDestinationIP) = struct.unpack('IIIIII',myBuf)
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 24
```

Here is my code:

```
import struct
import socket


#Dictionaries
uniqSource = {}
uniqDestination = {}

def int2quad(i):
        z = struct.pack('!I', i)
        return socket.inet_ntoa(z)


myFile = open('trace1.flow')
myBuf = myFile.read(8)

(magic, endian, version, headerLen) = struct.unpack('HBBI', myBuf)
print "Magic: ", hex(magic), "Endian: ", endian, "Version: ", version, "Header Length: ", headerLen
myFile.read(headerLen - 8)

try:
        while(True):
                myBuf = myFile.read(24)
                (secs, nsecs, booted, exporter, mySourceIP, myDestinationIP) = struct.unpack('IIIIII',myBuf)
                mySourceIP = int2quad(mySourceIP)
                myDestinationIP = int2quad(myDestinationIP)

                if mySourceIP not in uniqSource:
                        uniqSource[mySourceIP] = 1
                else:
                        uniqSource[mySourceIP] += 1

                if myDestinationIP not in uniqDestination:
                        uniqDestination[myDestinationIP] = 1
                else:
                        uniqDestination[myDestinationIP] += 1

                myFile.read(40)

except EOFError:
        print "END OF FILE"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to assume that `file.read` will raise `EOFError` on end of file, but this error is only raised by `input()` and `raw_input()`. `file.read` will simply return a string that's shorter than requested (possibly empty).

So you need to check the length after reading:

```
myBuf = myFile.read(24)
if len(myBuf) < 24:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your have reached end-of-file.  Check the length of myBuf:

```
len(myBuf)
```

It's probably less than 24 chars long.  Also you don't need those extra parenthesis, and try to specify duplicated types using 'nI' like this:

```
secs, nsecs, booted, exporter, mySourceIP, myDestinationIP = struct.unpack('6I',myBuf)
```